# Changing template literals variable's value inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been making a pokedex web app just for fun, but i'm struggling to change the pokemon's atributes so that the user can see multiple pokemon. I'm using the PokeAPI and made the url change with a template literal:

```
let pokeNumber = 1
let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}
console.log(url)

function getPokemon() {
fetch(url)
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})

.then((data) => {
    console.clear()
    console.log(data)

    document.querySelector('.poke_name').innerHTML = data['name'].toUpperCase()
    document.querySelector('.poke__peso').innerHTML = `Peso: ${data['weight']}kg`
    document.querySelector('.poke__altura').innerHTML = `Altura: ${data['height']}m`

    let img = data['sprites']['front_default']
    document.querySelector('.poke_img').setAttribute('src', img)
})


}

getPokemon()

document.querySelector('.btn_forw').onclick = () => {
console.log(url)
pokeNumber++;
console.log(pokeNumber)
}

document.querySelector('.btn_backw').onclick = () => {
console.log(url)
pokeNumber--;
console.log(pokeNumber)
}
```

Comment: You're missing a backtick on the second line `let url = \`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}` should be `let url = \`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}\``

Comment: you need to trigger `getPokemon` after changing `pokeNumber`, and also this way the number in `url` is not changing, as it's defined only once.
I suggest defining proper url inside `getPokemon` function.

Answer (score 0):

The variables inside a template string are not stored by reference, instead they are populated immediately when declaring that variable.

For example

```js
let userId = 1;

let url = `/user/${userId}`
console.log(url); // "/user/1"

// we're only changing the `userId` variable - not the `url` variable
userId = 2;
console.log(url); // "/user/1"

// we can then re-declare the `url` variable the same way
url = `/user/${userId}`
console.log(url); // "/user/2"
```

So generally what you need to do is re-declare the `url` variable each time you change any variable that it used to construct that string.

Alternatively, you could put it in a function and call that each time, e.g.

```js
function getUrl(){
    return `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}`
}

// or ES6 one liner
const getUrl = () => `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}`


// then instead of using `url`, replace it with the function call `getUrl()`
function getPokemon() {
    fetch(getUrl())
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
}

// alternatively, if you are not using the `url`
// variable outside the `getPokemon` function,
// you could re-define that within it:
function getPokemon() {
    let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNumber}`;

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
}
```